# Не правильно выводит код Java

Tags: java

```
stu[i] = new Candies("","","","");
stu[i] = new Candies("","","","");
stu[i] = new Candies("","","","");
System.out.println("Введите Тип");
stu[i].type = in.next();
System.out.println("Введите производителя");
stu[i].proizvoditel = in.next();
System.out.println("Введите состав");
stu[i].sostav = in.next();
System.out.println("Введите Название");
stu[i].name = in.next();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stu));
```

Вывод `[Candies@179d3b25, Candies@254989ff, Candies@5d099f62, Candies@37f8bb67]`
что делать

Answer (score 1):

Правильно всё выводит.

Если хотите, чтобы объект выводился как строка, то надо переопределить метод `toString`, а без него показывается лишь адрес в памяти

Comment: а как его переопределить я просто еще не очень знаю в Java

Comment: точно так же, как любой другой метод в Java.

Comment: у меня получилось а как можно сделать так что бы при вводе значений оно сохранялось в массиве объектов а не пропадало

Comment: а вообще можно как-то отредактировать строку массива объектов на пример я выбрал 1 и хочу поменять название конфеты